# Is there a standard way to move 3d cursor with axis constraints?

Tags: workflow, 3d-cursor

Let's say I want to snap the cursor to the face of the cube moving only along the X axis from the origin, preserving its Y and Z.

[image: cursor move on cube example]

It looks like all I need is to enable "snap to face", activate "constraint to X axis" and move the cursor with the "shift-RMB" towards the cube's face.
However, it does not work, because the cursor first "sets" to the point where I first click and only after that when I "tweak" the mouse the "axis constraint" can be applied which does not make any sense, because I have no way (?) to somehow align/snap that first click.

[image: axis constrain failed]

I found that if I disable the "set cursor" command in the "keymap"

[image: preferences]

it kind of works: although the cursor moves somewhat strange I can correctly constrain it to the axis and achive correct positioning.

[image: axis constrained successfully]

I am wondering is there a standard/official way to move 3d cursor with axis constraint in default configuration?

Comment: Go into edit mode and select that face, then use SHIFT-S > Cursor to selected. You can do the same with edges and vertexes.

Answer (score 1):

This was a good question.

You can use axis constraints with the 3D cursor.  Select the 3D cursor icon on the toolbar to your left.(shift+spacebar)  Then when you move the 3d cursor, you can use normal axis constraints by pressing X, Y, or Z as you are moving it.

[image]

If you are unsatisfied with this go to the sidebar and choose "View" and then "3D Cursor".  You can enter numeric values in XYZ for the cursor's location.

[image]

Of course you can also position your cursor with the wheel menu , as a previous commentator said, refer to his answer.